# Jenkins pipeline and Chef for Continues Deployment

Tags: maven, jenkins, chef-infra, jenkins-pipeline

I'm working on scenario, Jenkins is my CI tools and Maven is my build tool, ere I will be configuring the Jenkins pipeline through Jenkins file, but after the build steps are done, I want to deploy and install the artifacts (i.e .Jar files or some other) using chef(cookbooks-recipies) on the nodes, I was confused how can I achieve this process ! please help me
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This question is way too vague to get a useful answer, and even if you make it more specific it's a very very broad question. I've got a write-up of my most recent build of this at https://coderanger.net/jenkins/, feel free to crib from it in part or in full.

Comment: Jenkins pipeline setup for the continues integration and Deployment, My only confusion was how Jenkins and chef are going to communicate in this process, after the continue integration, I want the chef to take over and install the Jar packages and deploy them on the several nodes. Here maven is my build tool. In Jenkins pipeline I can setup until the build is done , is there any thing that I can do in the Post section of the pipeline for the chef communication for deployment or it has to be done from the chef/cookbook/recipes/name.rb, is there any Jenkins plugin that make it possible !

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins pipeline setup for the continues integration and Deployment, My only confusion was how Jenkins and chef are going to communicate in this process, after the continue integration, I want the chef to take over and install the Jar packages and deploy them on the several nodes. Here maven is my build tool. In Jenkins pipeline I can setup until the build is done , is there any thing that I can do in the Post section of the pipeline for the chef communication for deployment or it has to be done from the chef/cookbook/recipes/name.rb, is there any Jenkins plugin that make it possible !

Answer (score 0):

Check [chef plugin](https://github.com/melezhik/chef-plugin/) that lets you 
run chef-client on remote host.

Comment: But with the chef plugin, how can I install or deploy on vast number of nodes ?

Comment: I am not sure if there is a easy way to run on multiple nodes but even if you want to run on multiple nodes you would require to setup ssh key authentication on all nodes that you would need. Rundeck is very elegant when it comes to deployment using chef. After your build jobs are done, you can use Rundeck to execute chef client job with the help of plugin https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/RunDeck+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

In Jenkins, deploy to a container plugin will help you to deploy your code to any of the workstation and use knife to upload into chef server and get deployed to all the nodes